# How do I write this JS code to retrieve JSON data from my php file?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to populate a dropdown list to select countries and also to highlight the border of that country when selected.
This is for an application that displays a fullscreen map and gives you information on different countries that you select.
I need to figure out how to access my json files data using php and js.

I am using a json file that looks like this:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Bahamas","iso_a2":"BS","iso_a3":"BHS","iso_n3":"044"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-77.53466,23.75975]....
```

I have to use a php file to pass its contents to js (becuase I can't let the json data be passed to the clients side)
My php looks like this:

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

                $string = file_get_contents("/libs/js/json/countryBordersGeo.json");
    $decode = json_decode($string, true);

                $countries = [];
    foreach ($decode["features"] as $country) {
        array_push($countries, (object)["name"=> $country["properties"]["name"], "iso"=> $country["properties"]["iso_a3"],"geometry"=> $country["geometry"]["type"],"coordinates"=> $country["geometry"]["coordinates"]]);
    }
    echo json_encode($countries);
?>
```

I believe that my php file is correct but I am struggling to get this to all work in the js file.
Currently, my js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

    // Get the country information
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getCountryBorders.php",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            // ---------------- Generate Country Objects ----------------
          if (result.status.name == "ok") {
                
                name = result['features']['properties']['0']['name'];
                iso_a2 = result['features']['properties']['0']['iso_a2'];
                iso_a3 = result['features']['properties']['0']['iso_a3'];
                iso_n3 = result['features']['properties']['0']['iso_n3'];
                geoType = result['features']['geometry']['0']['type'];
                coordinates = result['features']['geometry']['0']['coordinates'];;.....
```

Would this be the correct way to write my js code?
I just need to access the json data, I hope I've explained this properly.
Thank you.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dreambold/pen/PoBobbr?editors=1011

Comment: Please have a look at the code and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: hello, thank you for your response. This hasn't worked do you know if potentially have a problem with my php file? or maybe do you have any other ideas for the js/ajax. Thank you again.

Comment: Did you try to copy the code I have added in the codepen?

Comment: hi, yes I did try the codepen but it didnt work unfortunately

Comment: Can you show me what `success: function(data) {console.log(data)}` shows in the console?

Answer (score 0):

> npm install axios

```js
import axios from 'axios';

axios.get('/your-php-file.php')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Hello, how could this allow me to have 'name' or 'iso_a3' etc be assigned a value from the json file? As console.log-ing wouldn't allow to assign the data to anything would it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).